# Get string value with double spaces in it

Tags: php, string, post

I have one string value such as `The string contains double  spaces`. I am fetching this string as:

```
$string = $_POST['sports']; //gives me output: The string contains double spaces
```

It returns me correct result when there are no double spaces in a string. But, if there is a double space as above example, it omits the double space and gives the string result.

I want to get the string value as it is. Any idea how can I get this?

Comment: You are receiving the exact same string but you are probably watching it in a browser where multiple spaces are collapsed. Check the source of the html.

Comment: @Liz please share the form or source page that is producing the POST request. The form could have some javascript that clears spaces or other fancy pants stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is not caused by PHP, but it how text is rendered in a browser. To make sure you also see the extra white space, you could wrap the text in a `pre` tag:

```
echo "<pre>$string</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The Browser probably suppresses your multiple Spaces. All you can do is to replace them with & nbsp;s as far as I know:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:  You can add &nbsp (No-break space) to get the same result

```
  $string = $_POST['sports'];
  $string = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $string);
```